# Generating regular expression using a set of regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on a regular expression that matches the postal codes of a set of countries. Since getting a regex that matches the postal code for any one country is relatively easy, I plan to parse all those regexes each of which matches the postal code for a country and output a regex which strictly matches the union of the input regexes.

I know about the | operator. But is there any such operator for C# regex / regexvalidator class

Answer (score 0):

Use the `|` alternative regexp operator:

```
regex1|regex2|regex3|...
```

This matches anything that matches any of the component regexps.

According to the answer in [Merge several regexes to a single one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888765/merge-several-regexes-to-a-single-one) the PCRE engine will optimize regular expressions that are merged this way.

Comment: Yes they can be "union"ed. But I was wondering whether this approach would be as efficient as a single regex output while working with a union of say 180 - 200 regexes

Comment: You mean try to figure out what all the regexps have in common, so those parts can be combined? That would probably be more efficient, but I don't know if there's a general algorithm for merging regexps like that.

Comment: thanks. I think I didn't search using the right keywords.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you have `REGEX1`, `REGEX2`, `REGEX3` that match to some postal code.
Use `REGEX1|REGEX2|REGEX3` than. You don't need to parse contents of regex'es.

Comment: Yes they can be "union"ed. But I was wondering whether this approach would be as efficient as a single regex output while working with a union of say 180, 200 regexes